# Can a write to a PCI memory-mapped register cause a CPU to freeze with no exceptions?

Tags: x86, driver, pci, pci-e

I'm debugging a driver for a PCI device. The registers for the device are memory mapped.

I've narrowed down the freeze to a single line:

```
*(pci_dev->registers + reg_offset) = RandomValue;
```

The freeze doesn't always happen, but when I run it on a loop it will happen in a minute or so.

What I don't understand is how this would freeze my CPU. I assumed that the worst that could happen is the device gets erratically unmapped at some point, which would cause a write to an invalid memory address, triggering some exception. Fine.

But I don't see any exception happening. No kernel oops or any output at all. My other cores seem to freeze too, although I'm not sure if that's because they're waiting for some spinlock or not.

Wouldn't this mean that a misbehaving PCI device, even if limited by an IOMMU, could arbitrarily decide to freeze a CPU? Is there some write message acknowledgement in PCI that my CPU/Chipset is waiting for indefinitely, causing the freeze?

This is in Linux on an x86.

Comment: What's the register offset? There's a command register that enables e.g. bus mastering, which I guess could cause all kinds of exciting stuff if the device is misbehaving.

Comment: What is the device, what state is it in, and what is the register (and why are you putting a random value in there)? Your question makes it sounds like you're throwing spanners into the most complex machine humans have ever created and expecting good things to happen.

Comment: The device can do anything after receiving this write, so it's not necessarily the write itself that caused the freeze.